# Problem moving lines (one by one) from one text file to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to create a program that moves the first line in a text file to another and then remove said line in the first file (i.e. they are moved one by one). This should continue until there aren't any more lines in the first file to be moved to the second file.

The problem I have is that the program freezes and won't quit properly. I have experimented with the code and reached the conclusion that the error probably is in the counting of lines but that's all...

Here is the code:

```
# Create the second file
open("file2.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig").close()

# Find out how many lines in file one
lines = open("file1.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig").readlines()

# Loop the amount of lines
while range(len(lines)) != 0:
    
    # Get the first line in the first file
    first_line = open("file1.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig").readline()
    
    # Write the line to the second file
    out = open("file2.txt", 'a', encoding="utf-8-sig")
    out.write(first_line)
    
    # Remove the first line from the first file
    all_lines = open("file1.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig").readlines()
    new_file = open("file1.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig")
    new_file.writelines(all_lines[1:])
    new_file.close()
```

I would really appreciate some help with the code and critic in general.

Comment: *range(len(lines))* will never be equal to zero

Comment: Here's a few points for you to consider: 1) Is changing the files one line at a time really needed? You can copy entire files in one go if needed. 2) `open(...).readlines()` and similar is not a great way of handling files, you're opening a file, reading from it and then never closing it. 3) You already have all the lines in the `lines` variable, there's no point in opening "file1.txt" again.

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat: 1) Yes, the files used are very large and the program need to be able to pick up where it left off in case the program is stopped in the middle of the process. For this reason the program need to copy one line at a time. 2) Thank you, I will look into that. 3) Thank you again.

Comment: CtrlZ: why will range(len(lines))  never be equal to zero?

Comment: @Lavonen The *range()* function return an instance of a *range* class. Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: Adding to what @CtrlZ mentions even if you change that to `len(lines) != 0` it will be wrong because your `lines` variable never changes.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the *move()* function from the *shutil* module will perform in an atomic fashion provided the source and destination files are on the same filesystem - i.e. very fast. All you need to do then is recreate the source file as an empty file to achieve the same effect

Comment: Just a heads up that constantly rewriting large files after every line  will make this painfully slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objective of your code seems to be to copy one file to another. The *shutil* module has functions that you could use to achieve that.

However, if you insist on writing it from scratch (no imports) then:

```
SOURCE = "file1.txt"
TARGET = "file2.txt"
CHUNK = 64 * 1024 # or whatever is most convenient based on memory constraints

with open(SOURCE, "rb+") as source:
    with open(TARGET, "wb") as target:
        while buffer := source.read(CHUNK):
            target.write(buffer)
    source.seek(0)
    source.truncate()
```

**Note:**

As we're opening the files in binary mode the encoding specification is irrelevant

Comment: Yes, the files are very large and the process needs to be able to pick up where it left in case the program is stopped fore some reason. That's the reason for the wierd structure of my code and the counter. The program basically has to do the whole process line by line.

Comment: @Lavonen So you need something that's transactional. You'll need to implement some kind of checkpoint so that you know where to restart from. One thing's for sure, you won't want to unconditionally create the target file each time you run the program. The advantage of doing it in the manner shown in this answer is that if the program is killed (for whatever reason) it can just be restarted because the source file won't change until the entire copy has completed. I'll edit the code to show how you can do this in chunks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like primitive transactional processing of the rows in a "todo" file and moving them into a "done" file then this might be more what you are looking for.

Rather than constantly re-writing our arbitrarily large "to do" file, let's maintain a small file that is just the row number (not index) of our last successfully processed row. Then we can use it to "skip" rows already processed.

Note this is VERY primitive and could lead to a row being processed twice in the event of failure but it should get you started.

```py
import os

TO_DO_PATH = "file1.txt"
TO_DO_CHECKPOINT_PATH = "file1_checkpoint.txt"
DONE_PATH = "file2.txt"

def process(row):
    ## ---------------------
    ## Presumably we are going to do "something" with the row
    ## not just copy it to the "done" file.
    ## ---------------------
    print(row)
    ## ---------------------

def set_checkpoint(row_number):
    with open(TO_DO_CHECKPOINT_PATH, "w") as f:
        f.write(str(row_number))

def get_checkpoint():
    with open(TO_DO_CHECKPOINT_PATH, "r") as f:
        return int(f.read())

## -----------------------
## Is there any work to do?
## -----------------------
if not os.path.isfile(TO_DO_PATH):
    print("there was no work to do")
    exit()
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## init a checkpoint file if it does not exist
## after this, everything looks like we are picking
## up after a failure
## -----------------------
if not os.path.isfile(TO_DO_CHECKPOINT_PATH):
    try:
        os.remove(DONE_PATH)
    except OSError:
        pass
    set_checkpoint(0)
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## Read the row number (not row index) of the
## last checkpointed row
## -----------------------
last_processed_row = get_checkpoint()
## -----------------------

with open(DONE_PATH, "a") as file_out:
    with open(TO_DO_PATH, "r") as file_in:

        ## -----------------------
        ## Skip rows we already processed
        ## -----------------------
        for _ in range(last_processed_row):
            next(file_in)
        ## -----------------------

        ## -----------------------
        ## Process rows one by one
        ## -----------------------
        for row in file_in:
            process(row)
            file_out.write(row)

            ## -----------------------
            ## Update the checkpoint
            ## -----------------------
            last_processed_row += 1
            set_checkpoint(last_processed_row)
            ## -----------------------
        ## -----------------------

## -----------------------
## We completed all rows of the input file
## it and the checkpoint can be reset.
## -----------------------
os.remove(TO_DO_PATH)
os.remove(TO_DO_CHECKPOINT_PATH)
## -----------------------
```