# Function that deletes a readed line in a file

Tags: python, function, file

Is there a **file** **management** library in python that has a **function** that: **once** a **line** has been **read** in a file, it **deletes** **it** (**the line**)?

I need it to know, in case the program stops due to an error (the program can stop due a unexpected computer shutdown), where in the file it has ended up. What I have done for now is rewrite the entire file except the line it is reading or delete the line equivalent for each iteration in the for function.

```py
with open(archivo, 'r') as f:
        lineas = f.readlines()
    for i, linea in enumerate(lineas):
        print(f'Procesando {linea}')     
        with open(archivo, 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(lineas[i + 1:])            
        lineas = lineas[i + 1:]
```

Comment: I would probably look to use a database as a queue of work to be done, but in a pinch rather than writing a file and removing a line over and over again, I would maintain a second file with just the index of the last processed row. once all rows were processed you delete both files.

Comment: Can you share any code or example of what kind of file is being read? As well as if you add a try/catch the program shouldn't 'stop due to an error'.

Comment: If my suggestion seems like something you want to implement, there was a question similar to this the other day and reviewing the answers might help you. If it does, you might think about closing this as a duplicate.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77898061/problem-moving-lines-one-by-one-from-one-text-file-to-another/77901095#77901095

Comment: the last update of the code, where I open the file and delete the line for each iteration:
with open(archivo, 'r') as f:
        lineas = f.readlines()
    for i, linea in enumerate(lineas):
        print(f'Procesando {linea}')
        
        with open(archivo, 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(lineas[i + 1:])            
        
        lineas = lineas[i + 1:]

Comment: (in case the program stops due to an error) the program can stope due a unexpected computer shutdown

Comment: If you have some code you have tried, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78002505/edit) your question and include it.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there's no built-in file management library that directly supports reading a line from a file and then deleting it.
The standard approach, as you've done, involves reading the file, processing lines, and then writing back the unprocessed lines, mainly due to how file I/O works in most operating systems.

For your requirement—to know where in the file the process stopped in case of an error—you might consider an alternative approach that involves less overhead than rewriting the file each time:

1. Track Progress Using a Separate File or Variable: Instead of deleting lines from the original file, you can keep track of the line number that has been processed. If an error occurs, you save this line number to a separate file or a persistent storage mechanism. Upon restart, you read this progress indicator and skip to the line you previously stopped at.
2. Process and Archive Processed Lines: Instead of deleting lines from the original file, move processed lines to a separate "archive" file. This approach keeps the original file intact and provides a clear record of what has been processed.

This is the code.

```
def process_file(filepath, progress_filepath):
    try:
        with open(progress_filepath, 'r') as progress_file:
            last_processed_line_number = int(progress_file.read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        last_processed_line_number = 0

    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        if i <= last_processed_line_number:
            continue  # Skip already processed lines
        # Process the line here
        print(f"Processing line {i}: {line}", end='')

        # Update the progress file
        with open(progress_filepath, 'w') as progress_file:
            progress_file.write(str(i))
```

Comment: This is essentially what I was recommending you consider.